# How can I easily change an oracle db "varchar" column to "date" when current format is mm/dd/yy

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a column in an Oracle 11g Database which consists of dates, currently in a string. However, I want to create a query which fetches and orders based on the dates. I do not believe I can do this unless they are dates, not varchars. How can I change this column (of 7k rows) easily and efficiently?

Example:

```
alter table TABLE alter column COLUMN date not null
```

However, I'm worried this will make me lose my data. If it does, I can always back it up, but I just want to see if there a way around that tedious procedure.

Comment: You can do your order using: `order by to_date( yourField, 'mm/dd/yy' )`

Comment: Oh okay! So, if I wanted to pull dates only from 2014, I could do this: `select (*) from TABLE where COLUMN > to_date(01/01/14, 'mm/dd/yy')` ? Or something along those lines?

Comment: No, sorry, you have to convert the column and then check it like: `to_date(COLUMN, 'mm/dd/yy') > to_date('01/01/14', 'mm/dd/yy')` or even better `EXTRACT(YEAR from to_date(COLUMN, 'mm/dd/yy')) >= 2014`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And you can't change the column the way you want. You will have to create a temp date column

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable add tempDate date not null;
```

Then update it with the date formatted:

```
UPDATE yourTable SET tempDate = to_date( yourVarcharDateColumn, 'mm/dd/yy' );
```

Then you drop your column and recreate it

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable DROP COLUMN yourVarcharDateColumn;
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD yourVarcharDateColumn DATE NOT NULL;
```

Then you Update it with the values in temp

```
UPDATE yourTable SET yourVarcharDateColumn = tempDate;
```

Then drop the temp column

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable DROP COLUMN tempDate;
```

**Edit**

As pointed by @beherenow in comments there is the option of RENAME a column that I forgot about.

So it would be:

- Add the tempColumn
- Update the tempColumn with the formated date
- Drop the old column
- Then rename the tempColum with the command:

> ALTER TABLE yourTable RENAME COLUMN tempDate to yourVarcharDateColumn;

Comment: why just not rename `tempDate` to `yourVarcharDateColumn` after dropping the actual `yourVarcharDateColumn`? )

Comment: @beherenow You are right. I totally forgot about rename. I will Update. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer was accepted, sorry for the delay. Fantastic answer! Thank you @beherenow for teaching me about `RENAME` as well!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy:

Example table that stores date values as `VARCHAR2`:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (dt VARCHAR2(100));

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('7/15/2014');
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('7/16/2014');
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('7/17/2014');
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('7/18/2014');
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('7/19/2014');
```

Failed attempt with `ALTER`:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY dt DATE NOT NULL;

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01439: column to be modified must be empty to change datatype
```

Knew that would happen.  Can't modify the column unless it's empty.  No problem.  Let's copy the table to a temp table via CTAS, then empty it so we can `ALTER`, and reload the data.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable_tmp AS SELECT * FROM mytable;

Table created.

TRUNCATE TABLE mytable;

Table truncated.

ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY dt DATE NOT NULL;

Table altered.

ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='mm/dd/yyyy';

Session altered.

INSERT INTO mytable (SELECT * FROM mytable_tmp);

5 rows created.

DROP TABLE mytable_tmp PURGE;

Table dropped.
```

The result: now you have a proper `DATE` column that you can `ORDER BY`.

```
DESC mytable

Name   Null?    Type
------ -------- ----
DT     NOT NULL DATE

SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY dt DESC;

DT
----------
07/19/2014
07/18/2014
07/17/2014
07/16/2014
07/15/2014
```

Comment: -1. going to take a while for a large table, and needs FK management (you will not truncate if you have this table referenced). 2x table size space is required. probably more redo generated than in Jorge's answer

Comment: @be here now, did you notice that the OP said the table is 7k rows? ==> Not a large table.  So instead of `TRUNCATE`, if we go ahead an do a `DELETE` instead, we're probably generating about 1-2 MB of redo. What's the problem?  Jorge's solution puts the new `DATE` column at the end of the table, which "shouldn't" matter academically, but in practice it could blow up poorly coded vendor provided software.

Comment: delete will not work for the same reason, unless you have cascade/set null specified in constraint DDL. and his 7k rows could easily be 7gb of blobs - you never know )

Comment: Post a better solution then.  Neither my solution nor Jorge's handles the FK.  Neither does your column-rename suggestion on Jorge's solution.  This is a structure change, not the kind of thing you would necessarily do on a live application during business hours if you like your job.  So you would probably: take an outage to pause application traffic to the DB, drop the FK, do your table restructure, then reenable the FK, then open up for traffic.  Or I'm open to other ideas -- so suggest a better solution instead of nitpicking.

Comment: DBMS_REDEFINITION. still 2x on space and redo, but 99.9% online. not as simple to implement as add column/ctas, though

Comment: Good idea.  However with DBMS_REDEFINITION, you still have to manage the FK.  Should I "-1" you for suggesting a solution that still requires FK management and does 2x redo & space? ... and OP was looking for "easily and efficiently".

Comment: you don't. you register dependent objects - oracle does all the stuff. you never manually delete/truncate, you never manually enable/disable FK, you never get FK violation

Comment: but if we revert from 24/7 highload back to "easily and efficiently", Jorge's solution has no issues with FK as it doesn't deal with anything other than a single vc2/date column (unless that column is FK'ed, which I consider to be unlikely)